# REST services getting empty result for User object

Tags: apex, rest, apexrest, rest-service

We set up a REST service to retrieve data from our org.

**Everything works great, except for the queries to the `User` object. When the query returns we get an empty list.**

This used to work (it was tested thoroughly), but *it must have broken with the Winter '20 or Spring '20 update*.

When I try the REST service as a System Administrator, I'm still getting an empty response for `User` object, but full responses from any other object.

I `System.debug()`ed the query from the REST request and ran it in the Query Editor (as System Administrator) and got a list of users.

All this leads me to the conclusion that there is a (new) permission somewhere that we're missing.
I'm currently slogging through the release notes for both Winter and Spring '20, but it would be great if somebody knows exactly what the issue is.

EDIT:
I'm wondering if it has something to do with the Organization wide defaults in Sharing Settings. `User` is currently set to `Private` for both internal and external.
I'm a little hesitant to test it because according to the [release notes for Spring '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_sharing_ext_owds_disabled.htm) that is not undoable?

Comment: Is this a query for a Site (Site Guest User) or for a normal User?

Comment: A normal user. Like I said, this is the System Administrator performing these queries.

Comment: My bad - skipped over that line in the question.

Comment: for the profile in question, what is the value of the `View All Users` permission and if this is an apex rest service, what is the sharing setting for the class in question?

Comment: It's the System Administrator. So `View All Users` is enabled. The class is `with sharing`, but so are the other classes that return other objects that do work.